# How do Xamarin.Forms layouts get translated into platform-specific layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I recently had a discussion with my team about Xamarin.Form layouts, and they thought Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout was brittle and hard to work with (personally I think they are very handy especially for proportional layouts, and from everything I remember reading, they are generally not a performance issue). They referenced [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/), which said to avoid using AbsoluteLayouts -- **but** that was an Android-specific article, and it was referring to [Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout/).

So that got me to thinking...does Xamarin.Forms.Layout somehow translate into Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout (I think they're completely different since Xamarin.Forms allows proportional sizing/position)? How ***does*** Xamarin.Forms translate various layouts into platform-specific layouts?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Great, thanks for the reference, I will attempt to dig into the code and discover the answer. Would you say to categorically avoid Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout?

Comment: @jbyrd The bottom line for an `Android.Views.View` is that the Forms'-based `VisualElementTracker` directly calls the native `View.Layout` method with `x,y,width,height` params to hardwire the controls placement. Forms has its own hierarchy parent based layout manager that performs the calculations. I have a client that has replaced the entire Forms layout system with a native conversion to Android LayoutParams and iOS constraints, it has a Fody-based build conversion and a runtime caching system and achieves *almost* native layout speed, totally smokes Forms' layout manager.

Answer (score 3):

Layouts work different in Xamarin Forms than their equivalents on the native platform. The XF Absolute Layout is **not** just a wrapper around the Android AbsoluteLayout.

Layouts in XF are similar to how they work in WPF and other Microsoft Platforms. The Layout first asks all its children to give it a preferred size (Measure). Then it uses its logic to arrange its children. The built-in controls wrap existing native controls (e.g. Entry maps to UITextBox on iOS and EditText on Android).

That being said. I agree that Absolute Layouts in general are not a good approach for supporting multiple screen sizes. There are other more flexible layouts that help you create a general approach to a "universal" UI.